# What's the usage of synchronized in Java?

Tags: java

I have written several years of C++. And just begin to write in Java. There are synchronized statements in Java. It's new to me and I found the following usage:

```
synchronized (NetworkManager.class) {/*some code*/}
```

and

```
NetworkManager myInstance = new NetworkManager();
synchronized(myInstance){/*some code*/}
```

I know that synchronized statements will block other synchronized access to the synchronized sections in an object. But I'm confused by the argument of synchronized.

What I think is that if I want to block some method then I should synchronize on **myInstance** in C++ for second example. If I create another instance, it should have no influence. Is this correct?

If it is correct, what happens with use of `NetworkManager.class`? Will the **.class** return a class object reference to `NetworkManager`. On which instances will it take effect? Or will it influence all `NetworkManager` instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`synchronized (NetworkManager.class) {//some code}` will acquire lock on the `Class object` of `NetworkManager` class. It will prevent *conccurent* access to `static fields and methods` of the `Networkmanager` class provided you have synchronized on the same Class Object (Networkmanager.class) while accessing those methods.
or

```
NetworkManager myInstance = new NetworkManager();
synchronized(myInstance){//some code}
```

In the above two lines, you are locking a particular instance of NetworkManager class (not the class itself).

Comment: Synchronizing on a `.class` does not prevent concurrent access to static fields and methods, unless access to those fields is explicitly synchronized on the **same** (Class) object. Nor does synchronizing on an instance prevent concurrent access to instance fields and methods unless access to those fields is explicitly synchronized on that **same** object.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel -  But there will always be only one Class Object. So, you will always be locking on it. I am talking about a general case (and yes I am assuming) where the JVM, Classloaders and classes are not tinkered with.

Comment: @TheLostMind Not necessarily (same class from different classloaders), but even assuming there is only one `Class` object then what you say in your answer is incorrect **and** incomplete: see my previous comment, and also: think about what happens if an instance method synchronizes on `.class`...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Ah. I got what you meant.. Thanks a ton.. I was thinking you were saying something else. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When using `synchronized (object)` the current `Thread` will obtain the monitor lock of the provided object (and release it when it exits the block **or** waits on the object). If the monitor lock is already held by a different thread, then the thread will queue for that lock and wait until it becomes available. In other words using synchronized provides exclusive access with `object` as mutex. Note that using synchronized also provides certain memory visibility guarantees.

When using `synchronized (myInstance)` you lock on the provided instance. All synchronized blocks using the same instance and the `synchronized` instance methods of this instance will use the same mutex.

When you use `synchronized (NetworkManager.class)` you lock on the `Class` instance of `NetworkManager`. All synchronized blocks using `NetworkManager.class` (assuming they are all from the same `ClassLoader`) and `static synchronized` methods of `NetworkManager` will use the same mutex.

So using `synchronized (NetworkManager.class)` does not lock on all instances. The only real difference between locking on an instance or on the `Class` object is that the former includes locking with regard to synchronized methods of the instance, while the latter includes locking with regard to synchronized **static** methods of the class; in all other ways they work the same: you lock on the provided object.

You might also want to read up on the [Java Concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: After read it .If I understood it . It is equal to C++'s way. The .class returns an instance . the synchronized lock this instance.

Comment: @zzy Exactly, but keep in mind difference between synchronized instance methods and synchronized static (class) methods.